# Find .extension and move to other directory

Tags: linux, shell, command

I've been trying to find .jpg and .mp3 in a certain directory and move it to another; I'm pretty sure this is the right command, however its not working.

```
$ find -iname *.jpg *mp3 -exec mv {} /Directory2 \;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should quote glob patterns in `find` expressions to prevent them from accidentally matching files in the current directory.

Also `-iname` only takes a single argument - if you want to match alternate patterns you can use `-iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.mp3'` and so on.

So (being careful about operator precedence)

```
find . \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.mp3' \) -exec mv {} path/to/Directory2/ \;
```

or, since you're using Linux, use the GNU `-t` form of `mv` and the multi-file placeholder `{} +`

```
find . \( -iname '*.jpg' -o -iname '*.mp3' \) -exec mv -t path/to/Directory2/ {} +
```

Comment: if I want to move it from Directory 1 to Directory 2 ? When I'm running it says :
mv cannot move [...] permission denied

Comment: @ForzaTekk replace the `.` (current directory) by the path of the directory that you want to search

Comment: its still showing the error mv : cannot move [...] Permission denied

Comment: @ForzaTekk what is your *actual* target directory? I assumed `/Directory2` was just used for illustration. The actual target will need to be a directory that exists and in which your user has permission to create files

Comment: Yes '/Directory2' is for illustration. The actual target is already created in the gameshell.